# I am using Qt 5.6 during compilation it stops and gives error about Qmake

Tags: qt

The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.6.3\5.6.3\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake.exe" crashed.
Error while building/deploying project untitled1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.3 MSVC2015 64bit)
When executing step "qmake"

This is the error i am getting 
I have tried doing
Clean
Build Again 
Run Qmake 
but all in vain

Comment: Re-install everything.

Comment: I have reinstall three time

Comment: but same problem every time

Comment: Did you try another kit so far?

Comment: You could give more details, for example OS version, compiler version, installation process, etc.

Comment: Do you have MSVC2015 64 bits installed?

Comment: yes MSVC2015 64bits installer  and the qt version is 5.6.3

Comment: and my os is windows 10

Comment: Try also to re-install MSVC includin deletion of directories.

Comment: make sure msvs compiler works for you, can you compile a project directly in MSVS 2015

Comment: Did you try building a different, simple project (with the same Qt Kit)? Perhaps one of the basic examples.  Maybe it is something in the project config?  Post your `.pro` file contents.

Comment: you can try the mingw version : https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.10/5.10.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.10.1.exe you will have less problem and you final code can be cross compiled with ease

Comment: I re-installed ms visual studio 2015 but now same error

Comment: now i am downloading qt 5.10.1.

Comment: how did you solve it?